# SyntaxError quoatation marks nested in quotation marks when finding the value of a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
url_2 = "https://icanhazdadjoke.com"
response_2 = requests.get(url_2, headers = {"accept" : "application/json"})
data = response_2.json()
print(data["joke"])
print(f"status: {data["status"]}")
```

Hi guys I was wondering why on the last line why the quation marks on data["status"] cause a syntax error, I've never had to encounter something like this, I always use the "" for everything, I have not been able to find a source where I can find the answer to this. In the documentation I spent 20minutes and didn't find one similar to my case, maybe I'm just blind.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have double quotations inside a double quotation.
Either do this for the last line,

```
print(f"status: {data['status']}")
```

or,

```
print(f'status: {data["status"]}')
```

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

This is actually read as two strings and one variable.
Like this:

```
"Str1"variable"Str2"
```

If you parse it:

```
"Str1"
variable
"Str"
```

This is syntax error because what you want to do with two strings and one variable is unclear.